# How to count number of objects in table, grouped by column in has_many, for which some conditions matter?

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I have a table called `cars (id, brand)`. Cars can have many `adverts (id, car_id, state, dealer_name)`.

I wanna count the number of **unique** cars, in groups of `dealer_name`, for which that particular dealer is the ONLY one having the car currently `for sale`

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cjstvXSZ2sWYNqfe6LRcTc/1 (the expected output from the query is written in there too)

I have managed to do this in an iterative fashion in a ruby application, doing one query for each `dealer_name`, however I fail to do it in a single grouping query.

Data:

```
cars
id    make
1     'BMW'
2     'Mercedes'
3     'Mercedes'
4     'Volvo'
5     'Volvo'
6     'Volvo'
7     'Alfa Romeo'

adverts
id    car_id  state       dealer_name
1     1       'sold'      'Dealer 1'
2     2       'for sale'  'Dealer 1'
4     3       'for sale'  'Dealer 2'
5     4       'for sale'  'Dealer 2'
6     5       'for sale'  'Dealer 3'
7     5       'for sale'  'Dealer 4'
8     7       'sold'      'Dealer 4'

expected output:
dealer_name   Number of cars with only this dealer having the car currently 'for sale'
Dealer 1      1
Dealer 2      2
Dealer 3      0
Dealer 4      0
```

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result. (As formatted text, no images.)

Comment: It's all in the fiddle, but I will add it here too

Comment: Great, since the question and answers will be here as a reference for a long time, but the fiddle will soon be gone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do a window count in a subquery and then use conditional aggregation in the outer query:

```
select 
    dealer_name, 
    sum(case when cnt = 1 and state = 'for sale' then 1 else 0 end) cnt
from (
    select 
        dealer_name, 
        state,
        car_id, 
        count(*) over(partition by car_id, state) cnt
    from adverts a
) x 
group by dealer_name
order by dealer_name;
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cjstvXSZ2sWYNqfe6LRcTc/9)**:

```
| dealer_name | cnt |
| ----------- | --- |
| Dealer 1    | 1   |
| Dealer 2    | 2   |
| Dealer 3    | 0   |
| Dealer 4    | 0   |
```

Note: that was a well-documented question, that SO could use more of!

Comment: If a dealer has no cars for sale, then it will not be included in the result set.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: ah yes, that's correct. I updated my query to handle it, although OP sample data does not contains such use case.

Comment: @GMB I wonder how you start thinking about problems like this. What was your approach? (Did you start with the SUM or with the subquery .. etc)

Can you suggest documentation/tutorials for strengthening SQL?

Answer (score 1):

If you can have duplicate cars for the same deal (sort of implied by your desire to count distinct cars), then then this is trickier.  Postgres does not support `count(distinct)` as an aggregation function.

One method is:

```
select dealer_name,
       count(distinct car_id) filter (where state = 'for sale' and min_dn = max_dn) as cnt
from (select a.*,
             min(a.dealer_name) over (partition by a.car_id, a.state) as min_dn,
             max(a.dealer_name) over (partition by a.car_id, a.state) as max_dn
      from adverts a
     ) a 
group by dealer_name
order by dealer_name;
```

Or you can use two levels of aggregation:

```
select dealer_name,
       count(*) filter (where for_sale and num_dealers = 1) as cnt
from (select dealer_name, car_id,
             bool_or(state = 'for sale') as for_sale,
             count(*) filter (where state = 'for sale' over (partition by car_id)) as num_dealers
      from adverts
      group by dealer_name, car_id
     ) dc
group by dealer_name;
```

These also return *all* dealers, even if they have no cars for sale.

Comment: There is no `dealer_id` column in the OP, just `dealer_name`.

Comment: @GMB . . . There *should be* a `dealer_id`.